# Ubuntu + Kubuntu on one USB?

Tags: 14.04, usb, kubuntu

I have an USB with Ubuntu on it, now  want to try Kubuntu. If there is still more than 1 GB on the usb left, can i just install Kubuntu on the same USB and try it from it? 
The second part of my question: are the terminal commands and their functionality in Kubuntu the same as in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to, according to here, it is only 56 kb http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/kubuntu-desktop, though I do not know what version of ubuntu you are running. Open up your terminal (ctrl alt t)

```
sudo apt-get install -y kubuntu-desktop
```

Then simply reboot

As for terminal commands, yes. But the interface is a little different.